O365 connectors within Teams will be deprecated
Recently started receiving the following warning on our GitHub MS Teams Channels :
Action Required:
O365 connectors within Teams will be deprecated and notifications from this service will stop.Learn more about the timing and how the Workflows app provides a more flexible and secure experience. If you want to continue receiving these types of messages, you can use a workflow.Set up workflow
Turns out that MS is retiring O365 connectors within teams, so I want to know how to solve this, should we wait for GithHub to rollout their Power Automate Flow? Or we would have to make a custom flow for this? What are you guys going to do?

This below blog explains, Why are we retiring Office 365 connectors? & How to transition from Office 365 connectors to Workflows. Please refer to the blog for more details: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/retirement-of-office-365-connectors-within-microsoft-teams/

the explanation is nice and all, but the Azure DevOps connector that we were using can only be replaced by a premium Workflow....

First of all sorry for reusing this thread but is due to the warning similarity.
The same warning was there for a connector we use from Azure Devops builds. But since Wednesday (2024-07-17) this message stopped appearing.
Not sure if that means that there will be no deprecation for the Azure Devops team's app, or that deprecation might have been postponed.
Anyone noticed the same?

They have just removed the footer message from the cards being posted, the deprecation is expected to happen.
(Update 07/17/2024: Due to customer feedback received around the footer message, it will be removed from the cards that are posted within Microsoft Teams.
link

Microsoft has extended the retirement timeline through December 2025 to provide ample time to migrate to another solution such as Power Automate, an app within Microsoft Teams, or Microsoft Graph. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/retirement-of-office-365-connectors-within-microsoft-teams/
